# Application Configuration File not showing up

Tags: c#, asp.net, enterprise

I created a new project to test the Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0. It asks me to select the PROJECT - ADD NEW ITEM - APPLICATION CONFIGURATION FILE. For some reason, I don't see the Application configuration file option. Please let me know how to fix it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is the item you're looking for, it's found by going to this menu:

[image]

Comment: Hi Aren, 
I was trying to add the app.config file to the asp.net web application project. But when I created a new asp.net server control project, the application configuration file option showing up. I guess app.config is not applicable to a web project. I am new to coding:) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yea, you need a web.config ("Web Configuration File") then.

Answer (score 0):

For an ASP.NET application, you need to add a web.config file, not app.config.
[alt text http://philippursglove.com/stackoverflow/addwebconfig.png](http://philippursglove.com/stackoverflow/addwebconfig.png)